# ¿Por qué se escribe "hacer" en vez de "hazer"?

Tags: etimología, historia

Hoy, escuchando música, he descubierto la pieza [*Fantasia que **contrahaze** la harpa en la manera de Ludovico*](https://www.google.es/search?q=fantasia%20que%20contrahaze%20la%20harpa%20en%20la%20manera%20de%20ludovico).
La pieza en sí es lo de menos; lo que me ha llamado la atención es la manera de escribir ***contrahaze***, así con Z (en vez de con C, como hoy en día).

Intrigado, me he ido al DLE para consultar la etimología de [**contrahacer**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AZ95NyA). Ninguna sorpresa: tal como suponía, viene de **contra** y [**hacer**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Jwhmcap), y éste a su vez del latín *fa**c**ĕre*. Con C.

*«Igual este hombre no escribía especialmente bien»*, me he dicho. Así que le he preguntado al CORDE por *"contrahaze"* y me ha sacado [12 concordancias](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=contrahaze&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000), un número suficientemente bajo como para plantearse que los 12 casos sean faltas de ortografía... hasta que le he preguntado por *"haze"* y me ha sacado [más de 24 000 concordancias](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=haze&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000).

Entiendo por tanto que a lo largo de los siglos se ha producido una evolución *fa**c**ĕre* - *ha**z**er* - ha**c**er, pasando de C a Z y de nuevo a C.

¿Es esto correcto? ¿Qué motivos hubo para estos cambios?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hasta el año 1500, si buscas en el CORDE "haze" y "hace", sale ganador el primero con diez veces más resultados que el segundo. Sin embargo, si limitas la búsqueda a entre 1500 y 1600, el número de resultados es muy similar (15 000 contra 16 000). Si limitas a entre 1600 y 1700, ya aparecen el doble de resultados de "hace" sobre "haze", aunque aún aparecen como unos 7000 de este último. Y además de todos estos, en cualquier época aparecen algunos (pocos) resultados de "haçe".

En su primera *Ortografía* de 1741, la RAE ya dijo que la Z solo debía usarse "siempre que la haya en el origen de las voces, como en *zelo, zéphiro* y *zizaña*". También dice que había de usarse "antes de las vocales *a, o, u*, en que tiene su propia pronunciación, como *zagal, gozo, zumbido*. Para los casos antes de *e* o *i* decía que se usara la C, que "es letra más castellana que la Z".

Pero claro, esto era ya en el siglo XVIII, y estamos hablando de que el cambio se produjo antes. En la *Ortografia castellana* de Mateo Alemán, de 1609, se dice:

> [...] porque tenemos la c, letra propia nuestra, que sirve aquel oficio [el de la k], aunque (sin advertir en ello) la tenemos por la ç; lacual, sin aquella pihuela ò cedilla es k, con que pronunciamos ca co cu. Avemosla llamado ç, hasta oi, no siendolo: i asi dezimos con ella diferentemente ça ce ci ço çu, para la ce ci, no es necesario poner cedilla, supuesto que no puede tener otro sonido [...].

Es decir, hacia el año 1600 ya teníamos *ça ce ci ço çu*, y posteriormente se estableció que la Ç debía desaparecer en favor de la Z, quedando *za ce ci zo zu*. Dado que también se tenía la C como letra "más castellana" que la Z, la evolución fue a que la gente escribiera con las letras que le eran más familiares.

En todo caso, resulta curioso ver en la propia ortografía de Mateo Alemán escrito "hazer". Por tanto debió de ser más adelante cuando se hizo el cambio a "hacer". Entiendo que la Ç y la Z debían de tener sonidos diferentes, los cuales se acabaron fusionando y acabó prevaleciendo la norma de no escribir con Z los grupos ze, zi a menos que la Z se usara en el origen de la palabra. ¿Cómo se escribía "hacer" en latín? *Facĕre*. No tenía Z, y por tanto la norma dictó que no podía ser *hazer* sino *hacer* (de ahí la "contraevolución" C-Z-C que mencionas en la pregunta).

Curiosamente, no hizo falta esperar hasta la ortografía de la RAE de 1741 para que diera comienzo la transición definitiva. [Según Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hace%2Chaze&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1600&year_end=1800&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Chace%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhace%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHace%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Chaze%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhaze%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHaze%3B%2Cc0), hacia 1720 fue cuando "hace" le ganó la batalla a "haze":

[image: "Haze" vs "hace"]

Por último, comentar que el diccionario de Covarrubias de 1611 recoge "hazer", y que la última aparición de este verbo en un diccionario fue en el de 1721 de Bluteau. En cambio, "hacer" aparece en el de 1611 de Rosal y en todos los de la RAE desde 1734 en adelante. La RAE se fundó en 1713 así que igual algo sí influyó, a juzgar por la gráfica.